# How do I pass two similar concrete objects to a method with interface parameters that implement generics in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the following interface declarations:

```
interface IOrder<T> where T: IOrderItem
{
     IList<T> Items { get; set; }
}

interface IDistro<T> : IOrder<T> where T: IOrderItem
{

}
```

I have two concrete classes, like so:

```
// DistroItem implements IOrderItem
public class Distro : IDistro<DistroItem>
{
    public IList<DistroItem> Items { get; set; }
}

// PerishableOrderItem implements IOrderItem
public class PerishableOrder : IDistro<PerishableOrderItem>
{       
    public IList<PerishableOrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly, I have a static service method for saving to the database:

```
public static void UpdateDistro(IDistro<IOrderItem> distro)
{

}
```

My problem is, how do I pass a distro of either concrete type to my static method? The following doesn't compile:

```
Distro d = new Distro();
UpdateDistro(d);
```

The error is:

`The best overloaded method match for UpdateDistro(IDistro<IOrderItem>)' has some invalid arguments`

Is contravariance the answer? I tried adding `<in T>` to the original interface declaration, but that added more errors that I was unable to resolve. This is my first in depth foray into interfaces and I'm sure generics is adding complexity, so there might be a fundamental lack of understanding here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
public static void UpdateDistro<T>(IDistro<T> distro) 
  where T : IOrderItem
{  
}
```

EDIT:

With empty implementations for `DistroItem` and `PerishableItem` classes (both implementing `IOrderItem`), I've got the following compiling without an error:

```
Distro d = new Distro();
PerishableOrder p = new PerishableOrder();

UpdateDistro(d);
UpdateDistro(p);
```

Comment: Yes, I did try that. It still complained when passing the `Distro` object. `UpdateDistro<DistroItem>(myDistro)` threw the same error.

Comment: I see this is getting upvotes. I'll mark it as the answer if you can show me the proper way to call the method.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to be a pain. I had remnants from other testing where I was casting to the interface types, etc. This works as desired. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a covariant generic parameter in your interface, you need to change the interface a little bit though to ensure that `T` is not uses contravariantly:

```
public interface IOrder<out T> where T : IOrderItem
{
    IEnumerator<T> Items { get; }
}

public interface IDistro<out T> : IOrder<T> where T : IOrderItem
{

}
```

To define `T` as coverient parameter (`out`), allows for implicit conversion of classes that implement your variant interfaces.